# Sphinx documentation on raspberry pi cannot access html

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-sphinx

I am trying to create Sphinx documentation for raspberry pi following this tutorial https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/documenting-your-code/7

Sphinx generates some html pages which I want to be able to access through a route from the homepage of my app as I am using Flask.

For example this would be a route in `app.py`

```
@APP.route("/docs")
def docspage():
    return render_template('docs/index.html', title='Docs')
```

and in my `layout.html`

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('docspage') }}">Docs</a>
```

The problem I am having is that html files in Flask can only be accessed if they are within the `templates` folder. Generating documentation through sphinx creates a folder named `_build` which is not inside templates.

I have tried moving the `_build_` folder inside of `templates` but this created a number of issues and also does not seem like it is the right way to do this as `_build` also contains many non-html files.

What is the correct way to setup a route for a documentation page when using Flask?