# How to open sphinx html documentation on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I've created my html docs on my raspberry pi in a directory `/docs` using `make html`.  Now how can I open these html files directly in the browser without having to copy them to my local machine?

I read about sphinx having its own server or something but I cannot find the information about this anymore.  How can I run a server to access these html files from a raspberry pi?

Comment: you need a web server running in the root folder of your docs: try this `python -m http.server 3000 --bind 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sphinx documentation on raspberry pi cannot access html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641082/sphinx-documentation-on-raspberry-pi-cannot-access-html)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. This question was asking how to run the server.  The other question was asking how to have routes to the docs in the flask app.  I also asked the other question which noone has answered yet.